# How to fix some text symbols in JSON android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-json

Below picture describes my problem -

[image]

How to fix some text symbols in JSON android

My Code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ToursViewHolder holder, int position) {

    tourData = tourDataList.get(position);

    holder.tourDate.setText(tourData.getTourDate());
    holder.tourTitle.setText(tourData.getTitle().getTitleRendered());

    Glide.with(context)
            .clear(holder.tourImg);
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(tourData.getTourEmbedded().getWpFeaturedmedia().get(0).getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFull().getSourceUrl())
            .into(holder.tourImg);

}
```

Comment: Try to set in HTML format :  holder.tourTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(tourData.getTitle().getTitleRendered()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
String title = Html.fromHtml(tourData.getTitle().getTitleRendered(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT);
holder.tourTitle.setText(title);
```